# how to use MongoDB for storing ejabberd messages?

Tags: mongodb, ejabberd

I am using `ejabberd` as an `XMPP` server. But i wish to store the messages that go through the server and also when was the message sent and to whom and by who. I googled it but could not find how to do it. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to write a hook in Erlang. See the [ejabberd documentation for events and hooks](http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_events_and_hooks/) Specifically this one :

`user_send_packet(From, To, Packet) -> ok`

Use the [erlang driver for mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/erlang/) . If that's "not possible"/"too difficult", i suggest you call a PHP/Python/Ruby script that just stores the message into mongodb. Its easy to do, but won't scale too well.

Hope this helps.

Some links :
[mongodb-erlang Erlang driver examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095845/mongodb-erlang-erlang-driver-examples)

PS : It's been sometime since i used eJabberd. Any corrections are welcome.