# MongoDB driver for Erlang

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, erlang

I got mongodb version 2.4.3 installed on Ubuntu 13.04
and I installed mongodb-erlang to `/usr/lib/erlang/lib/mongodb-master` (by make)
but if I try to start it I got this error:

```
Erlang R16B (erts-5.10.1) [source-05f1189] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)
1> application:start(mongodb). 
{error,{not_started,bson}}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but if all else fails you might have more luck with CouchDB as it is written in Erlang.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095845/mongodb-erlang-erlang-driver-examples), perhaps?

Comment: Riak is also written in Erlang. Unfortunately both Couch and Riak require either complex map/reduce functions, Lucene-style full-text indexes, or manual index inversion in order to gain the sort of general queryability you get out of the box with Mongo.  Both are rather more robust and fault-tolerant than Mongo, however.

Comment: That driver has dependencies. Ensure that all dependencies are present and built, then they should all be in the code path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, the `bson` application is not started; the `mongodb` application requires it.  Just run `application:start(bson)` first, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thx, but I still have a problem: 
1> application:start(bson).
{error,{"no such file or directory","bson.app"}}
2> cd("/usr/lib/erlang/lib/mongodb-master/deps/bson/ebin"). 
/usr/lib/erlang/lib/mongodb-master/deps/bson/ebin
ok
3> 
3> application:start(bson).                                 
ok
4> application:start(mongodb).
ok

Comment: You can use `-pa`: `erl -pa /usr/lib/erlang/lib/mongodb-master/ebin /usr/lib/erlang/lib/mongodb-master/deps/*/ebin`.  Not sure how to get it to find it without that option.